# Oledb cannot access file fix

Tags: c#, .net, excel, oledb

for a small project I need to create a DataTable filled with data from an Excelsheet. Im getting this data with using an Oledb connection. Sometimes other people are using this file on the server. So I'm getting the "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

```
private DataTable excelSelectStatement() {
        try {
            string par = this._colParameters.getParameterByName("SheetName", false, null).Value;
            excelDataSet = new DataSet();
            string ace12 = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + _selectionStatement + "';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';";
            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(ace12)) {
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + par + "$]", connection);
                da.TableMappings.Add("Table", "TestTable");
                da.Fill(excelDataSet);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { MessageBox.Show(e.Message); }
        return excelDataSet.Tables[0];
    }
```

Is there any way with completing this with Oledb?

Comment: What is the question? Do you get any errors and which ones? Do you mean that the code doesn't work on the server? Does the server have the Jet OLEDB providers?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Im getting the "The process cannot access the file because it's used by another process" error.